# Exception called on Width change

Tags: vb.net

I have the below code:

```
Dim widthS = 792
Dim setW = Me.Controls("TableLayoutPanel" + CStr(x))
setW.Width = widthS - 26
```

But whenever I try I get the exception `"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."`, I have tried `DirectCast()` but it has no effect, does anyone have a solution?
Thank you.

Comment: why not use `me.tablelayoutpanel.width=` ?

Comment: Because I have `x` set to an integer value.

Comment: Is this really `VBA`? YOu can't declare and assign a variable in a single statement (your first two statements are not valid VBA syntax) like you have tried.

Comment: @David If it is not VBA then I have no idea what it is, I'm using Visual Studio.

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio (and DirectCast is available) then it's VB.Net. I re-labeled it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to actually declare the variable types in the `Dim` statement. For VBA, which you labeled this, it could look like this:

```
Dim widthS as Long
Dim setW as Control

Set setW = Me.Controls("TableLayoutPanel" + CStr(x))
widthS = 792
setW.Width = widthS - 26
```

**EDIT**

It sounds like you are using VB.Net. The basic premise is the same, but in VB.Net you can combine the variable declaration and instantiation like:

```
Dim widthS as Long = 792
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have some more code that throws the same error:

    `If Not x = 3 Then_
    Dim setZS As Control_
         setZS = Me.Controls("Panel" + CStr(x))_
         setZS.Width = widthS - 26_
    End If` where `_` is a new line.